# AWS RDS - what is the best way for me to give access to a BI/DW system

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

We've engaged with a firm to build us a BI/Data Warehouse solution from our transactional system (AWS RDS Sql Server).

What is the best way for me to grant read only access to our DB through VPCs and Security Groups that provides the best security profile while still making the connection perform well for the ETL jobs to run?

Note, the BI side is running in Azure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPCs and Security Groups do not have the capability of making a database read-only.

You should create a database user that only has read access, or better yet create a read-replica server in RDS and only give them access to that. You will need to work with the firm you are hiring to determine how they will be accessing the database exactly so that you can open the Security Group rules correctly to allow them to connect to the database.